# Github oAuth using vue2 and django

Tags: javascript, github, vuejs2, github-api

I am trying to use github oauth for user signup/login.
In vue I am getting the code which is provided by github in call back. but when i am using this code to get the access token I am getting a CORS error.
code to get access token from github

```
const github_code = this.$route.query.code;
axios.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', {
    client_id: APP_CONST.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: APP_CONST.GITHUB_SECRET_KEY,
    code : github_code,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:8080/login",
   }).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp)
   }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
})
```

error that I am getting

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS headers are missing however if you do add those. The github does not permit login through localhost. This is not the problem with your code. You need to read more on CORS. This is basically you are trying to do post request from your localhost server to github server. This request will be only valid if your localhost server is whitelisted on github server which obviously is not a feasible solution. To get a better understanding of what CORS is create two different django projects and run them simultaneously on different ports from localhost and try to make a post request from one project server to another you will again get a CORS error. But then whitelist the localhost server in second projects settings and then when you again make a POST request from 1st server now it will be successful. To whitelist you can use the django-cors-headers package.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by getting access token from backed.
I was not aware of the flow of social login.
for future readers I am trying to explain what worked for me.

Steps:

```
 1.First create a app in github developer console get the client_id and client_secret_keys we will be needing that.


 2. from front end login button hit url (GET)(https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize) with client_id,
redirect_uri, scope, state

 3. github will prompt you to authorize after that it will redirect the user to the same url that was mentioned in redirect_uri(it must
be same as what you specified when creating the github app).

 4. In response from github you will get a code and state. the code will be used to authorise the user.

 5. send the code to your backend app. and do a request (POST) (https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token) with params as
client_id, client_secret (you got it from the github app you
created), code (you got from hiting first url), redirect_uri and
state.

 6. In response from github you will get access_token  ex: access_token=e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a&token_type=bearer

 7. Now use this access_token to do a request (GET) https://api.github.com/user?access_token=  you can pass it in query
parameter or in header.

 8. In response you will get the details of user like email, profile picture, etc. You can save these data in db and perform all the
checks you needed.

 9. From this data you can generate JWT depending on you backend structure and need.
```